# How to add xlabel, title to each subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to plot multiple heatmaps using the `plt.subplots`. An example I found is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some data that where each slice has a different range
# (The overall range is from 0 to 2)
data = np.random.random((4,10,10))
data *= np.array([0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0])[:,None,None]

# Plot each slice as an independent subplot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=4,figsize=(12,3))
i=0
for dat, ax in zip(data, axes.flat):
    # The vmin and vmax arguments specify the color limits
    im = ax.imshow(dat, vmin=0, vmax=2,cmap='Reds')
    # ax.xlabel(str(i))
    # ax.ylabel(str(i))
    i += 1

# Make an axis for the colorbar on the right side
cax = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.155, 0.03, 0.67])
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)

figtype = 'jpg'
fig.savefig('aaa.jpg',format = figtype,bbox_inches='tight')
fig.tight_layout()
```

The code succeeds if I comment the following two lines (which is done in the above example):

```
ax.xlabel(str(i))
ax.ylabel(str(i))
```

If I use the two lines, I get errors saying:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xlabel'
```

How can I make it correct?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When using the matplotlib object-oriented interface, the correct commands to use are `ax.set_xlabel` and `ax.set_ylabel`.

(Compare these to `plt.xlabel`, etc., for the state-machine interface).

Likewise, to set a title, you need `ax.set_title`

You can see all the available methods for an `axes` instance in the api docs, [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#axis-labels-title-and-legend).